# SugarCRM - Regular User Type User Cannot Login

Tags: authentication, sugarcrm

I have SugarCRM running and able to log in and out using the super admin account. I created a new user with type Regular User and defined it password because I unchecked the auto generation of password.

Even if I change the password through the database I cannot log in. But, if I changed the the type to Administrator that user can now login. Why is that? I want it to be a Regular User only.

Regards,
Ronel

Comment: Which version of Sugar are you running?

Answer (score 0):

In version 6.5.x I have found that there is a problem with password rules. Perhaps this is the case. Go to config.php and look at passwordsetting array. There is a minpwdlenght and a oneupper. Change 'oneuppper' to 'false' and match minpwdlenght to the lenght you want.

This solved my issue.